# JQuery AJAX Web Service call on SSL WebServer

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am making a POST to a webservice that is local to the webserver. Everything works great until I host the site at my SSL enabled webserver. The webservice path is relative, meaning, I am making no reference to the protocol. **eg. /webservices/method.asmx**

The POST results in a runtime error. Has anyone seen this before?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: theURL + "/" + method,
    data: body,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Broken: " + theURL + "/" + method + msg.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give the full error and the FireBug data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this project is done in .NET 2.0.. the web method seems to handle the input data differantly. I was able to get around this by just construction a query sting and passing it rather than a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you specify an absolute url, including the protocol https:// piece... I usually put a javascript variable in my masterpages/template for "baseURL" for the prot://host:port/apppath/ reference... where port is only included if not the default.  Haven't, iirc, seen such an issue.